# fatal: password authentication failed for user "user"

Tags: postgresql

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>psql -- U "user"
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
```

I'm getting the above error when trying to run postgresql from cmd line on windows. However, when I run it from the start menu (using the gui) the password works fine. I'm on a laptop logged in as a user. My IT dept set up this role to have most admin privileges, but not all. So I installed the software as a user when I created the password. I want to use createdb db_name on the command line. What is the proper way to access posgreSQL from windows command line? How do I get to createdb and beyong the authentication issue? I tried changing the pg_hba.conf file also and that didn't work.

Comment: Is "user" the user? Try passing the name of the user explicitly using --username. See the options here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Don't enclose the username in ""

Comment: @Gareth Lyons That did not work, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>psql -U username template1
```

username is your user to login
template1 is default database

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>psql -U "user"  and am still getting the error. The database doesn't exist yet. I am trying to use postgresql through the windows cmd line to enter: createdb dbname